# Appscript required for populating my doc as pdf with images uploaded from google form

Tags: image, forms, insert, doc

As you see my doc has the table for images and comments.

1. I need to replace the report number in the header (as same as the response from forms like for the first response will be report no. 1, for the second the report no will be 2 like that)
2. need to insert the image and resize to set in the column designated
3. replace the texts in the body of the table
4. repeat the same by copy the table as many times as the number of photos uploaded (that's why I give a question No of photos)
5. replace the date at the footer of the doc and insert page numbers.
6. at last save it as pdf and share it to the correspondent by mail

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCFRA.png)][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qxbun.png)

as I am not a coder I did not write any code for it. if anyone help me with this will help my career growth

thank you